# Using this() and base() in inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine, this, radix

So I'm creating an inventory system in c# in which every item is a class inheriting from other classes. Currenty I am working on a few test classes, one of them is Fish.
Fish inherits from Consumables which inherits from Items(the top level class)
Note: Consumables are stack-able items basically.

I want to create 2 default constructors in the Consumables class, one that takes no arguments:

```
public Consumable() : base() {
    quantity = 1;
}
```

just setting the quantity to 1.

And one that takes one argument, the quantity:

```
public Consumable(int Quantity) : this() {
    if (quantity <= maxStack)
        quantity = Quantity;
    else
        quantity = maxStack;
}
```

to set the quantity at creation. Now I thought using this() in the above code would force the child to use it's own default argumentless constructor as the this, but that doesn't seem to be the case. This is what I have for fish:

```
public Fish() : base() {
    name = "fish";
    ID = 1;
    variant = 0;
    maxStack = 20;
    desc = "A Fish of some kind";
    rarity = ItemRarity.Common;
}

public Fish(int QTY) : base(QTY) { }
```

What I want to happen is when Fish(int QTY) is called, i want it to call Fish() to set up the basics, then call Consumable(QTY) to set up the quantity as well.

Currently however, when Fish(int QTY) is called, it calls Consumable(QTY) which calls Consumable() instead of Fish()

Is there any way to get this to work the way I'm looking for?

Comment: Have you considered using a static factory method instead?

Comment: You can extract the code from the default constractor to an `InitDefaults` method, and call it from both constractors

Comment: I'm not sure what a static factory method is

Comment: I would go with refactoring out the code to an `Init`-like method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: as already suggested in some comments, here a possible solution with an init-method that is called from both constructors. Fish(qty) now calls the base constructors and the own Init-method (same as Fish()).

```
public Fish() : base() {
    Init();
}

public Fish(int QTY) : base(QTY){ 
    Init();
}

private void Init(){
    name = "fish";
    ID = 1;
    variant = 0;
    maxStack = 20;
    desc = "A Fish of some kind";
    rarity = ItemRarity.Common;
}
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 1):

CLR creates Baseclass instance at first only than Childclass. And there no way affect on it. In your case I propose to create method Initialize. [.net fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xqSiLc)

Consumable class

```
public void Initialize(){
    Console.WriteLine("Consumable.Initialize()");
    quantity = 1;
}

public  void Initialize(int Quantity){
  Console.WriteLine("Consumable.Initialize(QTY)");

  if (quantity <= maxStack)
        quantity = Quantity;
   else
       quantity = maxStack;
 }
```

and Fish

```
public Fish(int QTY){
   Initialize(QTY);
}

public void  Initialize(){
    Console.WriteLine("Fish.Initialize()");
   name = "fish";
   ID = 1;
   variant = 0;
   maxStack = 20;
}

public void Initialize(int QTY) {
    Console.WriteLine("Fish.Initialize(QTY)");
    Initialize();
    base.Initialize(QTY);       
}
```

Output:

[image]